# Gravatar is bugging out

Tags: bug, gravatar

I have a profile image from Gravatar, but ever so often when I load a Stack Overflow page, the loading fails and I get a broken icon image. The console shows the error

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Reloading the page usually fixes the issue for several minutes and page-loads, until later (maybe when the browser cache invalidates?) it may re-occur.

To be clear, it's *not* that I'm getting a wrong image - the image is not loaded at all. All other on-page resources are loading just fine.

[image: Example of header bar when broken]

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your setup. Might be your browser (e.g, addons), or firewall, or something in your connection that is dropping connections to that URL.

Comment: But why only for Gravatar and only on StackOverflow and associated websites? GitHub for example is fine (or at least I have not yet seen it albeit being active on that page about equally as much recently). And all other third-party includes on SO work as well.

Comment: Simple answer: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ but the behaviour you describe is rarely due to a specific site. After all, the browser will just be making a request to the same URL regardless of which site it encounters it in.

Comment: I'm at a different location today so maybe I can find out if it's my WiFi that's dropping requests. My guess was that in the wake of the Gravatar hack in 2020 they might've limited the request rate to their API and SO might exceed that limit if poor caching policy is defined for the documents. That was my gut reaction to why it's only happening on SE affiliated sites.

Comment: FWIW, SO uses Gravatar's link directly (https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c459886648fd2e153a518352292ab509?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG) while GitHub stores its copy on their own (https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/845152?v=4)

Comment: @AndrewT. True! I didn't even realize that. Unfortunately that fits both possible explanations so far, "some issue my setup has with querying Gravatar" as well as "some issue Gravatar has with SE's queries". Will need to look for other sites using Gravatar directly, or just implement my own HTML document.

Answer (score 1):

Over the years, I've found Gravatar to be inconsistent at best. However, I just discovered in *Profile* → *Edit profile* → *Change picture* there is now an option to "Upload a new picture," which I hadn't previously noticed.

I just updated my profile with this method, and it works beautifully—across all Stack Exchange accounts. I also went to *Profile* → *Network profile* → click "Update profile info" and imported the data from a primary account.